# DRM errors on startup

Tags: intel, drm

I have recently noticed these errors on startup (they occur every startup):

```
Jun 29 08:07:09 MATRIX kernel: [   10.773473] [drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun
Jun 29 08:07:09 MATRIX kernel: [   10.773876] [drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A
Jun 29 08:07:09 MATRIX kernel: [   10.773895] [drm:intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun
```

What do they mean and what should I do about them?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

Comment: There is an entry for this bug on a _Kernel Bug Tracker_:

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=79261 It seems that this error message should be a debug message only, so nothing serious.

Comment: @tommyk: Perhaps post an explanation of that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an entry for this bug on a Kernel Bug Tracker: [bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=79261](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=79261) It seems that this error message should be a debug message only, so nothing serious. It has been fixed anyway in `4.3.0-040300-generic`

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, i have accidentally caused this by installing ubuntu with UEFI "Secure Boot" enabled, and then trying to boot with "Secure Boot" disabled, try re-enabling it in your BIOS if you have it disabled.