# Problem with Ubuntu shooting

Tags: boot

I'm quite a newbie with Ubuntu, but i have to say that's a powerful OS. Despite that, today i got a problem starting it.
When i turn on my portable, i got the purple screen that asks which option to choose: Ubuntu, Advanced options for Ubuntu, and then the 2 memory test commands.

At first, i thought it was only a screen of setup, but then i get this code.

```
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
/dev/sdb1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sdb1: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found

/dev/sdb1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY: RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sdb1 requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v.1.22.1. (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) [   12.358363] [drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe B FIFO underrun
```

I think that the file system got corrupted (even i don't know how i did it).
Do you know when this problem occurs or how to solve it?

Thank you for the help! ;)

Comment: "The root filesystem on /dev/sdb1 requires a manual fsck" ;)

Comment: Can you use the system after you see this error? Do you have a live media available?

Comment: Have you run fsck?

Answer (score 2):

1 method to do this would be to boot from a live dvd, go to command line and do a

```
sudo -i
fsck /dev/sdb1
```

---

According to [geekstuff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/fsck-command-examples/) you should be able to do it from initramfs directly. If ...

```
# fsck -a /dev/sdb1
# echo $?
```

shows an error code 4 you can also do ...

```
# fsck -y /dev/sdb1
```

If it works an `exit` will restart the boot process.

Comment: i repaired all the problems! It was simpler than i thought. However, before the OS started, i got this message: [   12.358363] [drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe B FIFO underrun. Should I worry?

Comment: do you have a dual boot? if so see-> http://askubuntu.com/questions/642207/drm-errors-on-startup