# ubuntu server 16.04 get stuck on startup, show i915 **error** pch transcoder a fifo underrun

Tags: 16.04, server

My ubuntu server 16.04 suddenly get stuck on startup, and I cannot enter into the system, the error message is:

```
[drm:intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] **Error** PCH transconder A FIF0 underrun
```

I find a solved answer at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642207/drm-errors-on-startup?newreg=39bdb3aa18c04caaad6baad4663e6538), but I still don't know how to solve this problem.

Should I reinstall the system, or do sth else the fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meet with this problem because I change the grub setting of my ubuntu.

At the beginning, I want to disable blank screensaver, so I refer to the solved answer of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138918/how-do-i-disable-the-blank-console-screensaver-on-ubuntu-server). After I finish `sudo update-grub` and reboot my computer at the next morning, I meet with this error and cannot enter the system.

So, to solve this problem for me, I just revoke what I do about the grub and `sudo update-grub` and reboot.